# Validity of convolution theorems

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. I would like to known if any of the following formula can fail when each of the quantities are well defined:
$$ \mathcal{F}(f\ast g) = \mathcal{F}(f)\cdot\mathcal{F}(g) $$
$$ \mathcal{F}(f\cdot g) = \mathcal{F}(f)\ast\mathcal{F}(g) $$
$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f\ast g) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)\cdot\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g) $$
$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f\cdot g) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(f)\ast\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g) .$$

In case they do not always hold can someone provide a counter example (where each quantity is well defined)?

Comment: Isn't there a ${}^{-1}$ missing in $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(f*g) = \mathcal{F}(f).\mathcal{F}^{-1}(g)$?

Comment: @md2perpe, thank you, i made the edit.